# Why is a problem with tendons called tendinopathy?

Tags: etymology

Why is a problem with tend**o**ns called "tend**i**nopathy"?

i.e. why does the o in tendon change to an i?

Comment: Because it's mecical-speak.  You might also wonder about "tendinitis" and probably a dozen others.

Comment: The suffix "pathy", derived from the Greek pathos, means disease or disorder.  Tendinopathy is the general term and usually refers to a chronic degenerative disorder of tendons affecting older adults and the aged. It may, however, occasionally become acute (tendinitis) due to strain.  Then again, tendinitis is a specific acute condition due repetitive strain of a healthy tendon in younger adults.

Comment: @Centaurus updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The etymological path of of the word *tendon* is fairly winding. It ultimately comes from Ancient Greek τένων (transliteration: *tenōn*), meaning "tendon", which was pronounced with no *d*-like sound after the *n*. The stem of this Greek word, found in forms like the genitive singular *τένοντος (transliteration: tenontos*), was *τενοντ-* "tenont-". There are a few English words built on the Greek stem, such as [tenontoplasty](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenontoplasty), [tenontodynia](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenontodynia), [tenontitis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenontitis), [tenontomyoplasty](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenontomyoplasty).

English *tendon* is from a Medieval Latin noun *tendo* or *tendon* which was irregularly adapted from the Greek word. The stem of this Latin noun is either *tendōn-* or *tendin-.* (Note: when citing Latin forms, I'm going to omit vowel length markers on the final syllable, as the length of *o* in this position varied in Medieval Latin.)

The insertion of *d* in the Latin word is quite irregular, and the OED says it is probably due to analogy with the Latin verb *tendere* "to stretch". In contrast, the adaptation of the end of the word from Greek *-ων* to Latin *-o,* and the use of either *-ōn-* or *-in-* in the Latin stem, follows certain patterns that are common in Latin nouns.

For some reason, native Latin nouns with stems ending in *-ōn-,* and some with stems ending in *-in-,* developed the ending *-ō,* without *n,* in the nominative singular form (this form was used as the lemma or citation form of Latin nouns). Because of this, Greek nouns that ended in *-ων -ōn* in the nominative singular often were taken into Latin as noun the ending *-ō* in the nominative singular, and with stems in *-in-* or *-ōn-*. An example of a borrowing from Greek that was adapted with a stem in *-ōn-* is Latin *leo, leōnis* "lion", from Greek  λέων *leōn.*

So the change of o to i in *tendinopathy* is not *completely* arbitrary, but it isn't completely predictable either. It's a little odd, and as far as I know, there's no particular reason why the word couldn't have been formed as "tendonopathy" instead; or, on the other hand, why the English noun couldn't have taken the form "tendin" (like *margin, origin, virgin*) rather than "tendon".